# Is Sacrifice a Hypocritical Self-Brainwashing Concept?

Tags: logic, ethics

Parents of a doctor have been known to declare that they sacrificed a lot to put their child through school to become a doctor. They cite sacrifices such as not taking vacations, not buying alcohol, not buying new cars, and so on. Therefore, if sacrifice means what it means, the exchange of a greater value for a lesser value, does it imply that the child's medical degree is of lesser value than the vacations, alcohol, and cars?

Comment: "Sacrifice" means, in one sense, the opposite: to exchange something of lesser value for something greater. (http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/sacrifice). Not sure where brainwashing comes in.

Comment: sacrifice being the exchange of greater value for lesser value cannot be assumed a priori. It can be greater, or lesser, or equal.

Comment: @Swami Vishwananda If an exchange of equal or unequal values takes place, why is it called a sacrifice? When exactly does "sacrifice" emerge as a word with its own distinct meaning, apart form words like trade, commerce, credit and debit? Here's the reality: sacrifice is generally understood and used to mean to give up some value - and yet, therein lies the rub - give up some value in "exchange" for another value. Hence, sacrifice is a non-word, a false pretense of nobility, or some other such vague non-real notion.

Comment: @guessed If you and I are soldiers and I jump on a grenade to save your life, do you see that as no sacrifice, or equal, greater, or lesser sacrifice? There is no false pretense jumping on a grenade.

Comment: It is not a sacrifice since both of us are within the same proximity of the grenade's lethal range. Both of us would have died if neither of us jumped on it, but now only one has died. That is a net gain. On the other hand, if I grab you and use you as a shield against the blast, I am a murderer.

Comment: @James Kingsbery Brainwashing is that something was "given up" for something else. Isn't giving up something for something not called trade? What do the parents wish to imply by using the word "sacrifice" instead of "trade"? Is there some greater nobility in sacrifice? That would imply boasting or arrogance. If there is lesser nobility, that would imply ignorance or debasement. Sacrifice is a very loaded term, and its implications are insincere, no matter how it is interpreted.

Comment: It looks like a semantic trick with words; in the same way there tricks to show that 0=1; the parents are sacrificing something in exchange for something greater - their child's future; except really it's not an exchange or a trade; which is why those words aren't used; so @kingsburys definition holds.

Comment: It's because they view it as greater that word is used; drawing on the archaic sense of *sacrifice=sacer facer=to make sacred*; and recalling that the sacred is seen as higher (whether or not you personally agree with this notion).

Comment: It's the same in chess; one sacrifices a pawn (a lesser piece) to gain possibly a queen (a greater one); sacrifice is not the same as trade; when I but an apple for a pound it's called a purchase; when I exchange one car for another; it's called a trade; to use the word 'sacrifice' there is simply bizarre.

Comment: @Mozibur Ullah If actions that affect the manifestation of one outcome (vacations, cars, entertainment) versus another (a child's medical education) then all we know is that the finite resources of time, mental, and physical effort were spent to produce one outcome or another. Since one cannot concurrently spend the same resulting resource of $100,000 on choice A and B, then simply one has chosen one over the other. How does sacrifice come into play if the value, personally perceived as preferred or greater, was chosen?

Comment: @guessed: that's an exercise in economics; not philosophy.

Comment: @Mozibur Ullah Let's strip ourselves of language and compare the results only. From the results, we cannot reverse-engineer whether a sacrifice took place or economic transaction took place. The mind can complicate itself. At one level, it recognizes cause, effect, resources, limitations, etc., and proceeds accordingly, assessing data to make a decision and propel a physical manifestation. On another level, the mind ascribes to the foregoing process additional insights, such as there was a benefit or there was a sacrifice, and other superfluous musings that exist in the mind only.

Answer (score 2):

I would choose to rephrase the meaning of sacrifice to be "the exchange of a *perceived* greater good for a *perceived* lesser good."  Thus the idea of such an example might be expounded upon from the parent's point of view as, "We came across many situations where we perceived something like a vacation or car as a greater good than the child's education appeared at the day.  However, we had reason to believe that our perceptions were in err, and in fact the money was better spent on the child's education.  However, we as parents, recognize that there are probabilities involved.  Our child might not use that degree effectively.  However, we believe the Return on Investment (ROI) is good enough that we will sacrifice our guaranteed vacations and cars for a probability of improving our child's life in the future."

Comment: Whether perceived or actually verified, as long as the net outcome is an actual or perceived loss, a loss it remains. It certainly paints sacrifice in the light of stupidity, waste, and without any form of redemption - unless it pays a debt, and of course, then that is not a sacrifice, but the rightful repayment of what did not originally belong to the individual in debt in the first place.

Comment: "As long as the net outcome is a ... loss, a loss remains."  applies future knowledge to decisions made in the past.  Consider, if we play a game where you give me $10 and I flip a coin.  Heads I pay you $30, tails I keep your $10.  It comes up tails, so the net outcome is a loss.  Do you feel that game of chance qualifies as "stupidity, waste, and without any form of redemption?"  By the logic described, the answer is "yes, because I lost $10."  I think the real answer is more nuanced than that (and most likely leads to you asking for "best 2 out of 3" in many circumstances).

Comment: How does wagering on a game of chance, when the next event is uncertain, and at best only many more such events as a group are statistically understood, relate to sacrifice?

Comment: How does it not relate to when the next event [in a child's life] in uncertain, and at best only statistical studies are available to determine odds over all children?  In both cases, you are choosing two options, with different outcomes.  Keeping your $10 is akin to going on vacation, Wagering it is akin to "investing" it in your child.

Comment: Is the vacation less uncertain? What if it rains? What if you contract dysentery? Sacrifice now pivots around the degree of certainty? Events are full of dependencies and correlations, so let's take an all-things-equal uncertainties within each endeavor, some more uncertain, some less. Then, let's also add that some people are less averse to uncertainty, facing risks and failures repeatedly until they succeed, where others abandon some pursuit after less failures. The risk-reward ratio varies from circumstance to circumstance, and people have varying mettle. So what.

Comment: It sounds to me like you're more of the opinion that the term "sacrifice" is not meaningful at all.

Comment: Exactly. Sacrifice, in absence of any meaning due to its self-contradicting usage, can only weaken the mind's interaction with reality, and of course, weak minds can be exploited, whether the weakness is due to fear or confusion.

Comment: First, to the answer, this definition makes every bad deal into a sacrifice.  Clearly that is not the way the word is used.  To the questioner, sacrifice has no more conflicting usage than 'good' does.  Do you suggest we just discard all words concerning subjective morality?  Good luck raising a child with such a language!

Comment: @Guessed, may I suggest a slight change in wording to bring your phrasing more in line with where jobermark is going: "'Sacrifice' can only weaken the mind's interaction with its *perceived* reality." By your original wording, a parent could not make the claim of having "sacrificed" until on their death bed, when everything has been tallied and accounted for.  However, people use this word in practice before that point, suggesting that, from their point of view, there is a different meaning.  That meaning may be more consistent with this slightly rephrased wording than it is with the original.

Comment: @Cort Ammon "perceived" reality is an interesting argument. However, being perceived, does this not introduce a potentially subjective, therefore arbitrary, understanding of reality from which a mind will gather false strength, and then creates a problem for the mind when it is confronted with an "actual" reality that conflicts with the "perceived" reality upon which a mind's strength was speciously built? If a mind resolutely perceives something as red that in reality is blue, would not such a mind have a weak grasp of the real color?

Comment: @Guessed, there are many schools of philosophy which believe this is the case for all perception.  Much of these philosophical stances have been backed by neurological studies.  Generally speaking, we like to believe our perception is *close* to reality.  However, there are cases where that perception has been shown to be quite far from reality.  A trivial example would be optical illusions, and more complicated examples show up in interpersonal relationships.

Comment: It's a little bit hokey quoting a comedy film on the topic, but I think Men in Black actually captured this opinion quite well with a quote from Kay: "Fifteen hundred years ago everybody knew the Earth was the center of the universe. Five hundred years ago, everybody knew the Earth was flat, and fifteen minutes ago, you knew that humans were alone on this planet. Imagine what you'll know tomorrow. "

Comment: @Cort Ammon Actually, that's quite apt, even if hokey. The limits of rational understanding of reality are always expanding and increasingly empowering.

Answer (score 2):

Passive-aggression is a hypocritical brainwashing **strategy**.

In this case you are talking about a passive-aggressive claim against a debt that can never be repaid, as an attempt to garner compliance from the child, or praise from others that they feel they deserve and are not getting.

This has nothing to do with sacrifice.  A genuine sacrifice does not result in a debt.  If you do something and will try to collect on the debt later, that is investment, not a sacrifice.

Sacrifice, etymologically means 'making holy' usually returning something to a state of holiness.  Its most basic form (symbolized in holocausts of atonment or in Salic weregelt) may be the recognition and repayment of a debt, or its release (forgiveness in Germanic laws -- for-given-ness, the state of having had enough given for it).  To the extent that debts, when mishandled, become lies that put one in a state of sin, debt is a model for sin (Forgive us our Debts...).  But a real sacrifice never **creates** a debt.  It can only resolve one.

Comment: Etymological or actual definitions, as offered by various dictionaries, overtly or implicitly frame sacrifice as characterized by quid pro quo. Sacrifice a lamb, receive God's good graces. In chess, sacrifice a piece to gain a tactical, tempo, or material edge. Why not then call it, sacrifice, for what it is: an investment, or better still, an effort, whose outcome does not need to be guaranteed, but is intended to net benefit. Let it be known that sacrifice is intended for net gain, not net loss.

Comment: @Guessed -- But do any of them mention the future?  A sacrifice may be a trade, perhaps unequal, but it results in no debt.  You sacrifice the piece, but the opposing player does not owe you something in return.  You cannot compel God's good graces, and traditional sacrifice **paid a debt** and did not create a new one.  Sacrifice is intended to set things right, not create future opportunities.  Accruing obligations and putting things **out of balance** is the exact opposite of that.  That creates a new opportunity for failure instead of eliminating one.

Comment: "Let it be known" that sacrifice is intended for mutual net gain, and thus balance and resolution.

Comment: Then why call mutual net gain sacrifice? Why not call it exchange, invoking economic rules of debits and credits. How is paying a debt an act of sacrifice? If I give you $100, you are indebted to me $100. You are not sacrificing anything when you pay me back $100.

Comment: Why have shades of meaning on any word?   Why not just go all NewSpeak and throw 90% of them out?  We just don't.  Why not pay attention to what I actually said?  Paying a debt is not generally a sacrifice, but sacrifice, traditionally can be paying a debt.  The inclusion is one way, and only involves special cases, where you are giving something you would rather keep just to have forgiveness or to feel like you are doing the right thing.

Comment: So, one "sacrifices" new cars and vacations to "feel" that paying for a child's medical education is the right thing?

Comment: Since when is religiously-derived language ever half that functional?  Why do we call dissolving a debt 'forgiveness'?  There is a metaphor here that may not make total sense -- but is part of the meaning.  Unlike now, when debt has been largely rationalized by banking, traditional ancient cultures felt bad about debts, to the extent that the common Protestant version of the Lord's Prayer translates 'minor sins' as 'debts'.

Comment: @Guessed, precisely, if it is actually sacrifice.  If instead it is building a cache of obligations for future passive-aggressive manipulation, it is an investment.  Basically there is an ulterior motive and they are using the wrong word on purpose to forgive future extortion.  If they tell the child 'be what you want to be, and we are behind you' and then take toll, they have lied to him.

Comment: You are failing to read what I have already written.  I am investing more in this argument than you, to a degree that is unacceptable.  I am done taking part in it.  No, that is not a sacrifice.  Does it meet any of the criteria I am suggesting that make something a sacrifice?  Which ones?  Does it make any thing even?  Does it make anyone feel better than they would otherwise?  Does it have anything to do with righteousness that would suggest acceptable use of a religious word?  Either listen or shut up, anything else is hypocrisy.

Comment: Your points are good. Some of my comments were made out of sync with yours, so the context was lost.

Comment: Sorry to snap at you, I had not realized we might be reading each other's answers out of sync.  This is yet another instance when I should have suggested *chat* over *comments* as stoicfury constanty reminds me...